# Angular2 observable timeout

Tags: angular2-http

I have a ASP.NET core web application with angular2 for client-facing.For specific reasons I want to increase the timeout of Http calls from angular2 to back-end server from default to 8 minutes.I have tried the timeout operator as such but still ending up with default timeout(2 minutes)

```
getSystemDetailsBySystemTypeAndOwnershipCode(systemType: string, ownershipCode: string): Observable<any> {
    let productUrl: string = `/api/systemdetails/systemtypes/${systemType}/systems/ownershipcode/${ownershipCode}`;
    return this.http.get(productUrl).timeout(480000)
        .catch((error: any) => {
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
}
```

Any suggestions to increase timeout? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Hey@Karthinga welcome to Stack-overflow question should be easily understandable and you need to put tag related your question for fast response. please go through this links.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix .Increasing the **requestTimeout** of the http calls in the web.config file of the project solves this issue

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
</handlers>
<aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:10:00" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```